# Reading line of complete words from text file in C

Tags: c, string, file, text

My goal is to read from a text file blocks of text, of a pre-defined size, with the condition that each word must be complete. A complete word is considered as a set of consecutive alphanumeric or underscore characters. The remaining characters are considered as delimiters.

I'm reading the file line by line, and I check which is the first character that's a word delimiter. Then I put the buffer string ending there, and move the file pointer to the beginning of the word that got cut off.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* inputStream = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    char buffer[255], ch;
    int i, j;
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), inputStream) != NULL){
        for(i = 254, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++){
            ch = buffer[i];
            if (!((ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) || (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) || (ch >= 48 && ch <= 57) || ch == 95 || ch == 39 || ch == 0x5f)){ //Check if is not alphanumeric or underscore
                fseek(inputStream, -j, SEEK_CUR);
                buffer[i] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        } 
        printf("BUFFER:\n%s\n\n", buffer);
    }
    fclose(inputStream);
}
```

But it's not doing the verification correctly. An extract from the output that shows that there are still words that are not complete is:

```
BUFFER:
s não entrava qualquer sentimento de pesar, de tristeza, de aflição mais ou menos pânica, nem sequer, para tudo dizer na inevitável e tópica palavra portuguesa – saudade. Compreender-se-á já porquê. É certo que, e pelos vistos irremediavelmen

BUFFER:
te, me ia afastando da Europa, mas os tecidos vitais da barca imensa que me levava continuavam a alimentar as raízes da minha identidade mais profunda e da minha pertença colectiva: logo, não encontrava em mim razões para chorar um bem perdido, se re
```

When I print the character that enters the if condition, it is always nothing.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does "complete word" mean? When you say "with the condition that they must be complete words only.", what is "they"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel A word is a set of consecutive alphanumeric or underscore characters. The remaining characters are considered as delimiters.

Comment: Your line may not have been 255 characters. So searching from 255 backwards is wrong. First determine the end of the line read.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'v tried to do `while(buffer[i] != '\0') i--;` before the for loop, and initializing `i=254`, but the result is the same. Am I checking the end of the line in a wrong way?

Comment: To shortly point the issue, your trouble comes from the way you are looping with `fgets` : `fgets` reads 254 bytes from your file if your file has more than 253 bytes, less otherwise. `fgets` reads a NULL terminated C strings (man fgets), so the last buffer byte will be 0 in that case. As 0 is non alphanumerical, your code then **immediately break** the while loop and then print the buffer as **it was last read**, so the 254 bytes.

Comment: @Zilog80, `fgets` reads a line terminated by `\n` (or the buffer size max). That is often much less than 254.

Comment: You should: `int len=0; while (buffer[len]!=0) len++;` You cannot determine it from the end because you don't know if there was a previous line or where it ended.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You're right, i've omitted/missed that point. I should have guess that there was `\n` in its input file, considering its multiple lines output. They were near 255 bytes both, so i had guess for a one line big txt file and the `\n`point had slipped out of my mind...